# recommended way to handle Microsoft graph Application is over its MailboxConcurrency limit

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using GraphServiceClient to create/update events and got following error. is there better way/
mechanism to handle this kind of errors

```
{
      "error": {
        "code": "ApplicationThrottled",
        "message": "Application is over its MailboxConcurrency limit.",
        "innerError": {
          "date": "2020-06-30T10:09:41",
          "request-id": "8a293e9c-7510-4993-a1b3-f9e74ba6087c"
        }
      }
    }
```